# ms access error: you tried to execute a query that does not include '[TOTAL]/[FREQ]' as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have very little experience with ms access and I'm not sure how to get this to work. I'm getting the error in the Title with this query:

```
SELECT Sum(Sheet2.TOTAL) AS SumOfTOTAL,
       Sheet2.[CUSTOMER NAME],
       Max(Sheet2.[RECORDED DATE]) AS [MaxOfRECORDED DATE],
       Count([FREQUENCY]) AS FREQ,
       Sheet2.TYPE,
       Sheet2.[SALES PERSON INITIAL],
       [TOTAL]/[FREQ] AS [AVE TRANS VALUE]
FROM Sheet2
GROUP BY Sheet2.[CUSTOMER NAME],
         Sheet2.TYPE,
         Sheet2.[SALES PERSON INITIAL]
HAVING (((Sheet2.TYPE)<>"C A N C E L L E D"))
ORDER BY Sum(Sheet2.TOTAL) DESC,
         Sheet2.[CUSTOMER NAME] DESC,
         Max(Sheet2.[RECORDED DATE]) DESC;
```

Please let me know how I might be able to get this query to run.

Comment: Can you please provide me the table create structure(query to create this Sheet2 table in MS Access) and 2 rows of data ?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 0):

Access (and most RDBMS) do not allow selecting columns in a `GROUP BY` query which themselves are not either aggregates (e.g. `SUM` and `MAX`, which you have), or appear in the group by list.

The root cause of your problem is that you are using `Sheet2.TOTAL` in the select list, which is not either an aggregate or appearing in the group by list.  I can offer the following suggestion, which might be what you are looking for anyway:

```
SELECT SUM(Sheet2.TOTAL) AS SumOfTOTAL,
       Sheet2.[CUSTOMER NAME],
       MAX(Sheet2.[RECORDED DATE]) AS [MaxOfRECORDED DATE],
       COUNT([FREQUENCY]) AS FREQ,
       Sheet2.TYPE,
       Sheet2.[SALES PERSON INITIAL],
       SUM(Sheet2.[TOTAL]) / COUNT([FREQUENCY]) AS [AVE TRANS VALUE]
FROM Sheet2
GROUP BY Sheet2.[CUSTOMER NAME],
         Sheet2.TYPE,
         Sheet2.[SALES PERSON INITIAL]
HAVING (((Sheet2.TYPE)<>"C A N C E L L E D"))
ORDER BY SUM(Sheet2.TOTAL) DESC,
         Sheet2.[CUSTOMER NAME] DESC,
         MAX(Sheet2.[RECORDED DATE]) DESC;
```